# $X$ countable and $\exists$ $f : X \rightarrow [0,1] \Rightarrow \big(X,2^X, \sum_{\omega \in S} f(\omega)\big)$ is a probability space.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is exercise 3.1 in Chapter B of [Efe Ok Probability with Economic Applications](https://files.nyu.edu/eo1/public/books.html) (freely available online).

Part of the claim we are asked to prove is:

> Let X be a nonempty countable set. If there exists $f : X \rightarrow [0,1]$ and $p(S) = \sum_{\omega \in S} f(\omega)$ for every $S \in 2^X$, then $(X,2^X,p)$ is a probability space.

I do not see how this can be true. I have in mind for instance the trivial function $~\tilde{f} : X \rightarrow [0,1]$ with $\tilde{f}(\omega) = 0$ for every $\omega \in X$. If   $~\tilde{p}(S) =  \sum_{\omega \in S} \tilde{f}(\omega)$, then $~\tilde{p}(S) = 0$ for all $S\in 2^X$. But then $~\tilde{p}(X) = 0 \neq 1$ and $(X,2^X,\tilde{p})$ cannot be a probability space by definition.

What am I missing? Why is this not a good counter example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a good counterexample. In the exercise there is missing an additional condition on $f \in [0,1]^X$, namely $\sum_{\omega \in X} f(\omega) = 1$. Then everything works fine.